# How to choose between "cantidad" and "importe" for an amount of money/ currency?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

**Why am I asking**

During the review of the translation of a software, in the context on an invoice, from English into Spanish I was puzzled by the translation of *amount* by the use of *cantidad* from the translator (which he most probably translated right), since I always thought an amount of money was translated as *importe*.

Do note that I am not a native English Speaker.

**My research**

According to Collins dictionary the translation for **[Amount of money](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-spanish/amount)** is :

> 2. **(= sum of money)** "cantidad *f*", "suma *f*"
>      " ⇒ a large amount of money" "una gran cantidad *or* suma de dinero"
> 3. **(= total value)** "valor *m*"
>      a bill for the amount of "una cuenta por importe *or* valor de"

However the translation of *[Importe](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/importe)* seems to be more related to a strict amount of money :

> 1. **(= valor)**
>
>    a. [de compra, gastos, cheque] "amount"
>
> [...]
>
> 2. **(= coste)** "cost"

Linguee translations for *[Amount of an invoice](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=amount%20of%20money)* leans toward *importe* but for *[Amount of money](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=amount%20of%20money)* towards *cantidad* .

**My question**

From what I read, I think *cantidad* is more a general word for *amounts* regardless of their types but that *importe* is a more specific term, but I could be wrong.

As a translation has more intricacies than plainly looking for words in a dictionary, I wanted to understand if I could use both as their meaning seem to be close.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While "*Cantidad*" is referring to any quantity, not just money, "*Importe*" is the amount of money a thing is worth.

So for your translation *Importe* is the more correct, being that you are talking about money, but *Cantidad* is equally correct to emphasize the concept you want to conceal.

In short: Both words have similar meanings, but *Importe* is about **money** and *Cantidad* is any **quantity**.

From RAE:

**[Importe](http://dle.rae.es/?id=L5ZJY9e)**

> De importar.
>
> 1. m. Cuantía de un precio, crédito, deuda o saldo.

**[Cantidad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7CUEdL2)**

> Del lat. quantĭtas, -ātis, y este calco del gr. ποσότης posótēs.
>
> 1. f. Porción de una magnitud.
> 2. f. Cierto número de unidades.

Comment: Also, in domain specific accounting parlance (accountantese?) Cantidades are raw transaction values, sumas refer to working subtotals and importes refer to higher order totals. Importe total Is the final sum of a statement. Importe final or balance final, are the ending balances of a running total.

Comment: @hlecuanda - This looks like an answer to me.  Comments are ephemeral, answers are more stable.

Answer (score 1):

Basta con consultar el DRAE. Un importe (de importar: valer cierta cantidad, costar cierta cantidad) es a cuanto llega un precio, un saldo, una deuda, un crétido, etcétera. Y una cantidad es una cantidad, de lo que sea, pero también significa «Porción indeterminada de dinero».

- Tengo una buena cantidad de manzanas.
- Obtuvo una buena cantidad con la venta de su apartamento.
- Esa muchacha tiene cantidad de admiradores. (i.e. tiene muchos admiradores)
- El importe por los gastos en mantenimiento sobrepasa nuestro presupuesto.
- El importe había ido creciendo día a día, y a fin de mes llegó a 10 000 dólares
- Con esta cantidad podré terminar mis estudios.
- ¡La cantidad de mentiras que tuve que decirle a esa muchacha!

En ocasiones algunas personas usan la palabra «monto» para decir «importe», porque «monto» es la suma de varias partidas o cantidades parciales.

- ¿Cuál es el monto total?
- No hemos precisado el monto por temor a quedarnos cortos.

Sé que los ejemplos no son muy elaborados, pero aclaran en algo las diferencias.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answers, and following advise to include this as an answer rather than a comment:

In domain specific accounting parlance *(accountantese?),* Araising from the need to distinguish different levels of sums and working subtotals in accounting worksheets

- **Cantidades** are raw transaction values
- **Sumas** refer to working subtotals
- **Importes** refer to higher order totals, as related to particular accounts (Importe de costos de mercancía, importe de costos operativos, etc)
- **Balances** are the final figures in a financial statement (***Balance financiero***) indicating either profit or loss in a P&L statement or Balance sheet.
- **Posición** Is also a figure in accounting documents, however this term refers to an investment as related to equity or vested interest in futures.

Also:

- **Importe total** Is the final sum of a statement.
- **Importe final** or **balance final**, are the ending balances of a running total.

**Importe** also commonly refers to the face value of a single financial instrument such as a check,  stock certificates​, ***pagarés*** (I.O.Us) or government bonds, independent of their actual values, while **Importe total** Is the sum of the face values of a group of such documents, again, independently of the actual value of such a group, which is rather unsurprisingly called **valor actual**

However be aware that this may vary regionally  according to generally accepted accounting practices.